# How should sed global substitutions behave at end-of-line?

Tags: sed, posix

Consider the `sed` program `s/\(,\|$\)/-/g`. When run on various inputs under GNU `sed`, it gives the following interactions which seem a bit inconsistent:

- The empty string -> `-`
- `,` -> `-`
- `a` -> `a-`
- `a,` -> `a-`
- `,a` -> `-a-`

Whether the `$` part of the expression matches the end of the line seems to depend on whether the last match ended at the end of the line. My intuition says that the `g` flag should repeat the match from the end of the last replacement until the regex fails to match, in which case this program should always append an extra `-` to the line; but of course, my intuition doesn't necessarily match the POSIX specification.

Reading the POSIX manpage for `sed`, it says the following about the `g` flag to the `s` command:

> Globally substitute for all non-overlapping instances of the BRE rather than just the first one. If both g and n are specified, the results are unspecified.

Whether the last `,` in the input "overlaps" with the EOL or not seems to be open to interpretation. Is there anything else that might clarify this? Is this behavior according to specification, or is it a bug in GNU `sed`?

Comment: The notation you're using isn't supported by POSIX [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), so it isn't clear that it there's much to be said about what POSIX mandates.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I thought this was all according to POSIX. What part isn't?

Comment: `\|` notation for alternation is not part of POSIX `sed`, AFAIK.  It says, in part, _The `sed` utility shall support the BREs described in XBD [Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03)_.  That in turn says: _The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by a `<backslash>` ( `'\\'` ) is undefined, except for:

•    The characters ')', '(', '{', and '}'

•    The digits 1 to 9 inclusive (see BREs Matching Multiple Characters)

•    A character inside a bracket expression_

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Huh, you seem to be right. I did not expect that. Not sure where that leaves me. I'll have to investigate the situation further.

Comment: It mainly means you can't appeal to POSIX for the required behaviour.  I think that alternatives are evaluated left-to-right, but the `$` context occurs after the comma.  I briefly looked through your list (you say 'empty string' — I guess you mean 'empty line'?) and didn't see surprising behaviour.  The first match on the line always wins, doesn't it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yeah, I meant the empty line. However, after matching the last comma, there still seems to be an opportunity left to match the end-of-line, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111957/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-dolda2000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*As noted in comments, and then discussed more extensively in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111957/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-dolda2000)…*</sup>

The notation you're using (specifically, the `\|` to mean alternation) isn't specified by POSIX [`sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), so it isn't clear that it there's much to be said about what POSIX mandates.  It says, in part:

> The sed utility shall support the BREs described in XBD [Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03).

That in turn says:

> The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by a `<backslash>` (`'\\'`) is undefined, except for:
> • The characters ')', '(', '{', and '}'
> • The digits 1 to 9 inclusive (see BREs Matching Multiple Characters)
> • A character inside a bracket expression.

This mainly means you can't appeal to POSIX for the required behaviour. I think that alternatives are evaluated left-to-right, but the `$` context occurs after the comma. I briefly looked through your list and didn't see surprising behaviour. The first match on the line always wins, doesn't it?

I'm not sure exactly how it works, but I'd guess that the newline is removed from the line, then the substitution is done on the character before EOL, and the scan resumes but is at EOL, so it doesn't do anything more.

POSIX `sed` is probably expected to be implemented in terms of the POSIX [`regexec()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/regexec.html) etc functions.  You pointed out that the interpretation of the `g`-modifier is left to `sed`.  I suspect that it probably behaves more or less as I hypothesized.

In the chat, we also noted that:

- GNU `sed` has `-r` for using extended regular expressions, but they seemed to behave similarly (when the notation was changed accordingly).
- BSD and Mac OS X `sed` has `-E` for using extended regular expressions.
- Busybox `sed` appeared to work similarly, so the behaviour seems to be common across multiple implementations of `sed`.
- Using Mac OS X, we got unexpected behaviour for:

  ```
    $ echo ",a" | sed -E 's/(,|$)/-/g'
    -
    $
  ```

  In the absence of a better hypothesis, we designated that as 'inexplicable' or 'possibly (probably?) buggy'.  There's no obvious reason for the `a` to go missing.
- Using Perl or Python might be a sensible option.

Comment: Just for the record, I went through Busybox' actual implementation (since it was the smallest), and this particular behavior does not seem to be intentional per se, but rather a seemingly unintended consequence of how it handles patterns that might match the empty string (like `c*`). Specifically, it skips any zero-length matches that directly follow a previous match. It is perhaps not unlikely that the other implementations behave similarly for the same reason.

Comment: That makes sense, especially with the `g`-modifier; how else would you know when to stop matching the zero-length matches after the last substitution?